# "Argument of type 'string | undefined' is not assignable to parameter of type 'string'" for user.token

Tags: angular, typescript

I am working on a project using ASP.NET Core Web API and Angular 13.

The login post request from the endpoint is:

```
> https://localhost:44396/api/v1/auth/login

    {
       "status_code": 200,
       "message": "Successfully Logged In",
       "result": {
           "token": "gggggffffffffffffdddddddddddd",
           "user": {
               "id": 3,
               "user_name": "smith",
               "last_login": "2022-01-03T12:35:26.0305649"
              },
           "roles": [
               "Teacher"
           ],
           "expires": "2022-01-03T14:40:33Z"
       }
    }
```

This is the Angular code:

`user.ts`:

```
export interface IResponse<T> {
  message: string;
  error: boolean;
  code: number;
  results: T;
}

export interface IUser {
  userName?: string;
  lastLogin?: Date;
  token?: string;
  roles?: string[];
  expires?: Date;
}
```

`auth.service.ts`:

```
export class AuthService {
  baseUrl = environment.apiUrl;
  private currentUserSource = new ReplaySubject<IUser>(1);
  currentUser$ = this.currentUserSource.asObservable();

  constructor(private http: HttpClient, private router: Router) { }

  login(model: any){
    return this.http.post(this.baseUrl+'auth/login', model).pipe(
      map((res: IUser)=>{
        const user = res;
        if(user){
          this.setCurrentUser(user);
        }
      })
    )
  }

  setCurrentUser(user: IUser){
    if(user){
      user.roles = [];
      const roles = this.getDecodedToken(user.token).role;//copy token to jwt.io see .role
      Array.isArray(roles) ? user.roles = roles : user.roles.push(roles);
      localStorage.setItem('user', JSON.stringify(user));
      this.currentUserSource.next(user);
    }
  }

  getDecodedToken(token: string) {
    return JSON.parse(atob(token.split('.')[1]));
  }
}
```

I got this error:

```
error TS2345: Argument of type 'string | undefined' is not assignable to parameter of type 'string'.
```

With this code highlighted in `setCurrentUser`: `user.token`

How do I resolve it?

Comment: What did you _expect_ to happen? Per the definition of `IUser`, `token?: string` - it's optional, a given user might not have a `token` property. But the `getDecodedToken` function defines its parameter as `token: string` - that **must** be a string. _Somewhere_ you need to deal with the fact that those don't add up - we can't tell you exactly how, you need to decide if those types are correct and, if so, what _should_ happen if `user.token` is `undefined`.

Comment: @jonrsharpe - After login, I want to store toekn user_name, last_login, roles into the local storage

Comment: And again, what should happen if the `user.token` is `undefined`, as the types you've defined allow it to be, when you come to pass it to `getDecodedToken`. Also you seem to be dealing with a token like a JWT but not actually _validating_ it - what did you think the other parts separated by `.` were for?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Please try

```
const roles = this.getDecodedToken(user.token || '').role;
```

Comment: And what do you think getDecodedToken does with an empty string? This passes type checking, but is otherwise completely wrong.

Answer (score 1):

try to change the **"if (user) { "** in your code by this:

```
if (user && user.token) {
```

It should be enough to TypeScript to know that *user.token* actually exists, despite the fact that your interface says that it is optional.

If it doesn't work, try this variation:

```
if (user && user.token != null) {
```

Answer (score 0):

You can change the interface:

```
export interface IUser {
  ...
  token: string;
}
```

If you're certain you'll always get a token, as long as you get a user.

Alternatively, you can explicitly assert string type:

```
// Change this:
this.getDecodedToken(user.token)
// to this:
this.getDecodedToken(user.token as string)
```

And best to do is to make sure you have one, like the other answer suggests:

```
if (user && user.token) {...}
```

Comment: `user.token as string` does **not** cast it, it's just a [type assertion](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/everyday-types.html#type-assertions) (and if the original type is correct, one that's potentially a lie).

Comment: Correct, thanks, edited the post.